# How to tag-jump in Objective Perl in Vim?

Tags: perl, vim, tags

Nowadays I'm working with [Objective Perl](https://metacpan.org/pod/ObjectivePerl) using `::` with `->` as well.

However, Vim doesn't recognise a tag which is pre/appended with `::`.

Is there a way to solve this?

ex) I can jump when it is Foo->foo() but can't do once BAR::bar().

Comment: Can you post a short example of the "non-working" syntax?

Comment: Is that really supposed to be `::`? Or just a typo, and you meant `:`? Please add a code sample.

Comment: (And since I can't comment on my own upvote to explain why I +1'd squeaky) +1 on SqueakyOctopus offering potential solutions / workarounds while I presume waiting for the OP to post a code example.

Comment: @satyrwilder  it is definitely ::

Answer (score 1):

Update:  Since I don't have a code sample that demonstrates the failure, I'm trying to find things that are helpful.  As I stated below, basic Vim isn't going to have that functionality for custom marking, but plugins to Vim will get you further.  Fritz Mehner's perl-support.vim plugin has been around for years and is quite good:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=556

There is a new plugin by Valloric found here that has a lot of language support (but this is one that I haven't personally tried):

https://valloric.github.io/YouCompleteMe/

---

Original post:

Hmm, usually when I am coding something more complicated in Perl than a command line script or a handful of lines in a file, I use emacs as my editor, not vim, because emacs has hooks to a debugger and quite frankly has better support for complicated syntax.  There's a native perl support in emacs, but the better one is in cperl-mode in emacs.  That's going to have a lot of bells and whistles in it and it's really what you want.

I do use Vim often as a basic editor, but I think that coding in Objective Perl gets you to that place where it's not going to be as robust as you'd like.

To get to cperl-mode you can add the following lines in your .emacs file:

;;; cperl-mode is preferred to perl-mode
;;; "Brevity is the soul of wit" 
    (defalias 'perl-mode 'cperl-mode)

You can see more about it here at the EmacsWiki:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CPerlMode

(What I'm trying to say here is that getting support in Vim for :: and -> syntax is going to likely require custom marking and that isn't in Vim basic.  Instead, there are some packages like Fritz Mehner's perl-support.vim that might be helpful, but really, Vim isn't the best editor at the point where you jump to complicated syntax with classes (packages). You have to add a plugin or you have to find another solution.)